# Qt5: How to execute a "task" based on a weekly scheduler?

Tags: multithreading, qt, task, schedule, concurrent-programming

I am using Qt5 on Windows7 platform.
I have an app running 24/24, that it's supposed to connect to some remote devices in order to open or close the service on them. Connection is done via TCP.
For each day of the week there is/should be the possibility to set the hour&minute for both operations/tasks: open-service and close-service, as in the code below:

```
#define SUNDAY      0
#define MONDAY      1
//...
#define SATURDAY    6

struct Day_OpenCloseService
{
    bool automaticOpenService;
    int  openHour;
    int  openMinute;
    bool automaticCloseService;
    int  closeHour;
    int  closeMinute;
};
QVector<Day_OpenCloseService> Week_OpenCloseService(7);

Week_OpenCloseService[SUNDAY].automaticOpenService = true;
Week_OpenCloseService[SUNDAY].openHour = 7;
Week_OpenCloseService[SUNDAY].openMinute = 0;
Week_OpenCloseService[SUNDAY].automaticCloseService = false;
//
Week_OpenCloseService[MONDAY].automaticOpenService = true;
Week_OpenCloseService[MONDAY].openHour = 4;
Week_OpenCloseService[MONDAY].openMinute = 30;
Week_OpenCloseService[MONDAY].automaticCloseService = true;
Week_OpenCloseService[MONDAY].closeHour = 23;
Week_OpenCloseService[MONDAY].closeMinute = 0;
// ...
Week_OpenCloseService[SATURDAY].automaticOpenService = true;
Week_OpenCloseService[SATURDAY].openHour = 6;
Week_OpenCloseService[SATURDAY].openMinute = 15;
Week_OpenCloseService[SATURDAY].automaticCloseService = false;
Week_OpenCloseService[SATURDAY].closeHour = 23;
Week_OpenCloseService[SATURDAY].closeMinute = 59;
```

If `automaticOpenService` is true for a day, then an open-service will be executed at the specified hour&minute, in a new thread (I suppose).
If `automaticOpenService` is false, then no open-service is executed for that day of the week.
And the same goes for the `automaticCloseService`...

Now, the question is:
How to start the **open-service** and **close-service** tasks, based on the above "scheduler"?

Ok, the open-service and close-service tasks are not implemented yet, but they will be just some simple commands via TCP connection to the remote devices (which are listening on a certain port).
I'm still weighing on how to implement that, too... (single-thread, multi-thread, concurrent, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic implementation of a scheduler will hold a list of upcoming tasks (maybe with just two items in the list in your case) that is kept sorted by the time at which those tasks need to be executed.  Since you are using Qt, you could use [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html) objects to represent the times at which your upcoming tasks need to be done.

Once you have that list set up, it's just a matter of calculating how many seconds remain between the current time and the timestamp of the first item in the list, and then waiting that number of seconds.  The [QDateTime::secsTo()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#secsTo) method is very useful here as it will do just that calculation for you.  You can then call [QTimer::singleShot()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) to make it so that a signal will be emitted in that-many seconds.

When the qTimer's signal is emitted and your slot-method is called, you slot method will check the QDateTime of the first item in the list; if the current time is greater than or equal to that item's QDateTime, then it's time to execute the task, and the pop that item off the head of the list (and maybe reschedule a new task for tomorrow?).  Repeat until either the list is empty or the first item in the list has a QDateTime that is still in the future, in which case you'd go back to step 1 again.  Repeat indefinitely.

Note that multithreading isn't required to accomplish this task under Qt (and using multithreading wouldn't make the task any easier, either, so I'd avoid it if possible).

Comment: I was thinking just like you propose above, yet I'm afraid there is a problem here: Suppose the user (the GUI will provide that in the final version of the app)  decides to change the automatic open/close hours... Then what happens with all the singleShot() timers that are still active? Are there any means to kill/delete a running timer? You see, my concern here is that all the scheduler mechanism could be messed up by the timers... I'm pretty sure you understand what I mean :)

Comment: About your note on multi-threading: What I meant is that, for the sake of user-interface (GUI) responsiveness, I suppose it would be wise to throw the open/close task (TCP connections to remote devices) on a new/separate thread...  Am I right?

Comment: For your first concern (cancelling of running timers), I'm not aware of a way to cancel the timer, but it isn't necessary to do that because your connected slot-method should be able to handle early or late wakeups gracefully.  In particular, when it is called, it should be checking the current system time and executing only those tasks that were scheduled at or before the current time, and then recalculating time-until-next-event and setting a new timer for that time.  That way it will always work even if it gets a signal "too early", it will just do nothing and go back to waiting.

Comment: (to avoid accumulating spurious wakeups over time, though, it might be better to instantiate a single QTimer object and call setSingleShot(), start(), and stop() on it as necessary, rather than QTimer::singleShot(), though)

Comment: About multithreading, if you are using Qt's QTcpSocket class for your networking then you can write your network code to be event-based (i.e. non-blocking) so that the network operations are driven by emitted signals, e.g. the readyRead() signal is emitted whenever there are more bytes available to read from the QTCPSocket.  Then your connected slot just reads the available bytes, acts on them (or stores them in a buffer if they don't constitute a full message yet), and returns immediately, and thus never blocks the GUI event loop.